# Como agrupar array com os mesmos ids em novo array?

Tags: php, sql, array, foreach

Estou usando uma função em php para obter os dados custom fields do whmcs sql, mas a operação retorna os dados em um array, separando cada id por produtos.
O seja, ele não retorna o do produto com todos os `fieldname`, retorna vários arrays para o um único produto.

Preciso que esses IDs(`fieldname`) fiquem juntos em um array.

Minha lógica de array está abaixo.

**Código:**

```
Array(
[0] => Array([id] => 3[fieldname] =>  GA Domain[value] => teste.net)
[1] => Array([id] => 4[fieldname] =>  GA Domain[value] => gbr.com)
[2] => Array([id] => 5[fieldname] =>  GA Domain[value] => )
[3] => Array([id] => 3[fieldname] => GA PurchaseOrderID[value] => )
[4] => Array([id] => 4[fieldname] => GA PurchaseOrderID[value] => whmcs_account_4)
[5] => Array([id] => 5[fieldname] => GA PurchaseOrderID[value] => )
[6] => Array([id] => 3[fieldname] => GA AlternateEmail[value] => meupessoal54511@gmail.com)
[7] => Array([id] => 4[fieldname] => GA AlternateEmail[value] => galternate.com)
[8] => Array([id] => 5[fieldname] => GA AlternateEmail[value] => teste@teste.com)
[9] => Array([id] => 3[fieldname] => Mailbox Name[value] => testeuser1)
[10] => Array([id] => 4[fieldname] => Mailbox Name[value] => meltay)
[11] => Array([id] => 5[fieldname] => Mailbox Name[value] => meunome2)
[12] => Array([id] => 3[fieldname] => GA FirstName[value] => First Name)
[13] => Array([id] => 4[fieldname] => GA FirstName[value] => Mel)
[14] => Array([id] => 3[fieldname] => GA LastName[value] => Last Name)
[15] => Array([id] => 4[fieldname] => GA LastName[value] => Tay)
)
```

Preciso que o array fique com algo parecido como está abaixo.

**Código:**

```
Array(
[3] => Array([id] => "3", 
    ["GA Domain"] => "teste.net", 
    ["GA PurchaseOrderID"] => "",
    ["GA AlternateEmail"] => "meupessoal54511@gmail.com", 
    ["Mailbox"] => "testeuser1",
    ["GA FirstName"] => "First Name",
    ["GA LastName"] => "Last Name"),
[4] => Array([id] => "4", 
    ["GA Domain"] => "gbr.com", 
    ["GA PurchaseOrderID"] => "whmcs_account_4",
    ["GA AlternateEmail"] => "galternate.com", 
    ["Mailbox"] => "meltay",
    ["GA FirstName"] => "Mel",
    ["GA LastName"] => "Tay"),
[5] => Array([id] => "5", 
    ["GA Domain"] => "", 
    ["GA PurchaseOrderID"] => "",
    ["GA AlternateEmail"] => "teste@teste.com", 
    ["Mailbox"] => "meunome2",
    ["GA FirstName"] => "",
    ["GA LastName"] => "")
)
```

Abaixo está o código php usado no whmcs para gerar o array:
**Código:**

```
function products_list_hook($vars) {

    $client = Menu::context('client');

    $productcf = Capsule::table('tblcustomfields')
                ->join('tblcustomfieldsvalues','tblcustomfieldsvalues.fieldid','=','tblcustomfields.id')
                ->join('tblhosting','tblhosting.id','=','tblcustomfieldsvalues.relid')
                ->where('tblhosting.userid',$client->id)
                ->where('tblcustomfields.type','product')
                ->where('tblcustomfields.fieldtype','text')
                ->select('tblhosting.id','tblcustomfields.fieldname','tblcustomfieldsvalues.value')
                ->get();

    $encodedata = json_encode($productcf);
    $decodedata = json_decode($encodedata, true);

    return array("ProdCustomFields" => $decodedata); 
}
add_hook("ClientAreaPageProductsServices", 1, "products_list_hook");
```

Isso está gerando vários arrays, e o `foreach` abaixo que estou usando no template whmcs `{foreach item=field from=$ProdCustomFields} {if $field.id eq $service.id}` não está sabendo lidar com eles corretamente.

Como eu poderia alterar este array, para que ele gere um único ID para todos as keys e values relacionados como demonstrado, afim de obter um `foreach` mais preciso?

Comment: Tentei fazer um `array_merge`, porem não funcionou, como preciso usar isso no `foreach`, um exemplo simples em `php` seria bem-vindo, mas não necessário para responder a questão.

Comment: Acredito que você possa dar um array_push. Segue documentação: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-push.php

Comment: Agradeço a sugestão @NicolasPereira resolvi de forma diferente, deixo a pergunta aberta por alguns dias caso tenham outras opções com o mesmo resultado. Respondi com minha solução, pois não achei como fazer isso para o caso dos custom fields, espero que ajude outros a não passar pelo que passei :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com o código abaixo é possível resolver o problema no array, recriando o array com base no `id`, sendo assim atendendo ao que é pedido aqui.

**Código:**

```
$GA_Domain = "GA Domain";
$Mailbox_Name = "Mailbox Name";
$GA_FirstName = "GA FirstName";
$GA_LastName = "GA LastName";

$out = array();
$arrayobj = $decodedata;
foreach($arrayobj as $data => $value) {
    $arr_id = $arrayobj[$data]["id"];
    $arr_value = $arrayobj[$data]["value"] ?? '';

    if(strpos($arrayobj[$data]["fieldname"], $GA_Domain) !== false)
    {
        $out[$arr_id]['id'] = $arr_id;
        $out[$arr_id]["$GA_Domain"] = $arr_value;
    }
    if(strpos($arrayobj[$data]["fieldname"], $Mailbox_Name) !== false)
    {
        $out[$arr_id]['id'] = $arr_id;
        $out[$arr_id]["$Mailbox_Name"] = $arr_value;
    }
    if(strpos($arrayobj[$data]["fieldname"], $GA_FirstName) !== false)
    {
        $out[$arr_id]['id'] = $arr_id;
        $out[$arr_id]["$GA_FirstName"] = $arr_value;
    }
    if(strpos($arrayobj[$data]["fieldname"], $GA_LastName) !== false)
    {
        $out[$arr_id]['id'] = $arr_id;
        $out[$arr_id]["$GA_LastName"] = $arr_value;
    }
}

return array("ProdCustomFields" => $out);
```

Para chamar no template whmcs, basta utilizar o código abaixo com o `foreach`.

**Código:**

```
{foreach item=field from=$ProdCustomFields}
    {if $field.id eq $service.id}
        {$GSUsername=$field['Mailbox Name']}
        ...
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Isso permitira exibir e manipular os dados de forma organizada de acordo com o `$service.id`

Referencia do código no whmcs: [Display product custom fields on clientareaproducts.tpl page](https://whmcs.community/topic/280541-display-product-custom-fields-on-clientareaproductstpl-page/)

Adaptando o código você poderá manipular qualquer *custom filed*, conforme suas necessidades.